# video not loading via script on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a script that is supposed to show load a video only on desktops and display an image banner only on mobile.  This works fine in firefox and chrome, but the video doesn't load at all on safari.

The console shows these errors :

```
[Error] TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function. (In 'a.indexOf(" ")', 'a.indexOf' is undefined)
    load (jquery.min.js:4:18902)
    Global Code (uiscripts:1:22070)

[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.validator.addMethod')
    (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js:2:31697)
```

My html is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(
  function() {
    var bgv = $('#bgvid');

    if (bgv.is(':visible')) {
      $('source', bgv).each(
        function() {
          var el = $(this);
          el.attr('src', el.data('src'));
        }
      );    
      bgv[0].load();
    }
  }
)
</script>

<style>
    .hidden {
    display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
      .hidden {
         display: block;
       }
    }
</style> 

<video id="bgvid" class="hidden hidden-xs" autoplay loop>
  <source type="video/mp4" data-src="my-video.mp4"></source>    
</video>

<img alt="" class="visible-xs" src="my-image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```

Comment: The code as shown doesn't throw this error on Safari or other browsers. Substituting a working video URL and running this in Safari works as expected. Something else in your page is contributing to this problem

Comment: Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbGJwX

Comment: Other questions [suggest](//stackoverflow.com/q/38871753) that incompatible jQuery versions may be to blame. Nothing to do w/the code above, if so -- more likely other code trying to use out-of-date jQuery methods.

Comment: It looks like the code works when the video is hosted elsewhere, but if I use the url for the file on my local server it doesn't load (on safari only)